# How can I set a layout_Above with 2 values?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

Right now, I have a layout that looks like one of the two images below, depending on the exact size of the screen. Bot that on one, the Play Game! button is on top, and on the other, the copyright text is on top.

[image] [image]

What I'm trying to do is to put an image between the adview and the higher of the top text box/layout. Depending on different screen sizes, the entry that's on top can vary. I would like to not have this problem at all... I know how to put it below the imageview, but not put it above both items.

So far, I've tried a relativeLayout that encloses the bottom variables, and told the image to be above that, but below the AdView. Problem is, the top of the RelativeView goes clear to the top, despite it being set to wrap_content and none of the below values go that high.

I've also considered aligning either the top of the text to the top of the button, or visa versa, but I'm seeing a potentially ugly interface in my mind, one in which the top button might be bigger, or part of the copyright text obscured.

So, I'm looking for one of two solutions. A way to tell my image to be above 2 items, the button and the text, or some way to wrap the context such that I can just be above the wrapped value.

Here's the relevant XML code I've tested.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></com.google.ads.AdView>
  <ImageView android:src="@drawable/start_logo" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/logo_view" android:layout_below="@+id/adView" android:layout_above="@+id/buttons_copyright"></ImageView>
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/buttons_copyright" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  android:layout_alignParentTop="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   (NOTE: LOTS OF STUFF GOES HERE)
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a layout that will work for you - it looks like this:
Edit: Try this one...

[image]

Use this layout (replace the top button with your ad) 
(changed a bit since last edit to use anther relative layout...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"></Button>
    <TextView
        android:text="Version Text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/instructions_button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/instructions_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/instructions_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Instructions"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Game Name Text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/scores_button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scores_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scores_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="High Scores"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/instructions_button" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/copyright_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/scores_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Copyright text goes here and goes on and on a bit and fills up a few lines and looks ok generally and keeps on going and going and going and going onto many lines longer thatn it should etct"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Game!"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/scores_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/copyright_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/map"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What happens if there's a slightly different sized screen, and the copyright question is larger? I've seen this happen in different sized emulators, hence the question. I've tried putting in similar code in myself, so...

Comment: I've added a bit more description that explains what I'm trying to do it, and why. The bottom line is, your version wouldn't work on every size phone I need to support, so...

Comment: It should do now. One final thing you could do would be to wrap that text in a scroller and set maxLines to say, 5.

Comment: I like the suggestion from the comment. Hmmm.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for the comment you made. What I ended up doing was putting the copyright text into a scrollview, with the scrollview aligned to the top of the Play button. This allowed me to not worry that the layout would cause a problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'd dynamically resize the Font so that the buttons don't grow so big and that the text stays in relative size across different screen widths.